# ¿Tendremos más de 3 moderadores simultáneamente?

Tags: discusión, elecciones, moderadores

### Contexto

Hemos pasado ya mas de un mes, desde que nuestro sitio pudo oficiar la primera elección oficial de moderadores, y como buenos ciudadanos hemos hecho uso al derecho de votar.

Habiendo ya elegido nuestros tres primeros moderadores oficiales , [Alvaro Montoro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/250/alvaro-montoro), [Lois6b](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/15855/lois6b) y [Jorgesys](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/95/jorgesys). He visto que en el [sitio de la elección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/election), aparece el histórico de elecciones, en nuestro caso, solo aparece una elección, pero [en el sitio de elecciones de Stack Overflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/election) aparecen varias fechas de elecciones con sus respectivos elegidos. Y al revisar el listado de moderadores de dicho sitio, hay más de una decena de moderadores.

---

### Pregunta

Podría hacer dos preguntas afines en esta publicación.

#### 1) En las próximas elecciones de moderadores en nuestro sitio, ¿se reemplazaran a los que estan actualmente?

#### 2) ¿En qué se basa para decidir si un sitio amerita o no más de los tres moderadores?

Comment: Que yo sepa el puesto es vitalicio y se deja de ser moderador uno mismo voluntariamente o si se es echado del puesto por conductas inapropiadas o problemas. Supongo que el numero de moderadores se basa en la necesidad de ellos. Para ello existen estadisticas de actuacion de los moderadores en cuanto a tiempo de respuesta y numero de reportes resueltos. Si el sitio crece y 3 no son suficientes supongo que será JuanM quien decida que son necesarios más.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. **¿En las próximas elecciones de moderadores en nuestro sitio, se reemplazaran a los que estan actualmente?**

   No. El puesto de moderador diamantado es vitalicio. Esto está explicado en el [Centro de Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators):

> Los moderadores son elegidos de por vida, si bien pueden renunciar (o, en casos muy raros, ser destituidos).

2. **¿En que se basa para decidir si un sitio amerita o no mas de los tres moderadores?**

   En la publicación de meta [When do moderator elections take place?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99512/when-do-moderator-elections-take-place) se explica lo siguiente:

> The community team periodically looks at the work load on graduated sites and will reach out to the moderation team if it looks like more help might be needed. Broadly, it's up to the moderation teams to indicate whether they need additional hands, and how many sets of hands would be ideal.

y

> Most elections are scheduled as a result of moderators reaching out to Stack Exchange to ask for additional help.

Lo que traducido viene a ser:

> El equipo de la comunidad revisa periódicamente la carga de trabajo en los sitios graduados y preguntará al equipo de moderación si es posible que se necesite más ayuda. En general, corresponde a los equipos de moderación indicar si necesitan manos adicionales, y cuántos juegos de manos serían los ideales.

y

> La mayoría de las elecciones se programan como resultado de que los moderadores contacten con Stack Exchange para pedir ayuda adicional.

Comment: Buena respuesta, Pikoh. Por ejemplo las últimas elecciones en SO, este verano, se convocaron para poder hacer frente al mayor número de reportes debido a que con el nuevo diseño hay menos revisores ([fuente](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351972/2017-moderator-election-qa-question-collection#comment491095_351972)). Es decir, se convocan... cuando hacen falta más manos.